# Alternative for .string pseudo op?

Tags: macos, assembly, mach-o

I am trying to run an assembly file on Mac OS X that uses `.string` pseudo-ops, which apparently aren't recognized.  How should the following lines be replaced so it will work on a mac?

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
.long 35
.string "Array index out of bounds exception"
```

The line I am using to execute the assembly file is:

```
gcc -m32 -g3 runtime.c foo.s -o foo
```

Where `runtime.c` is a file with functions that can be invoked by `foo.s` program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.asciz`, or if you don't have that then whatever you have for ascii text and add a terminating `0`  byte manually.

**Update**: if you have `.asciz` then just use that in place of `.string`:

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
.long 35
.asciz "Array index out of bounds exception"
```

Otherwise if you have `.ascii` use something like:

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
.long 35
.ascii "Array index out of bounds exception"
.byte 0
```

Comment: Can you show what the whole block of code would look like?